# How to skip mocked image and get real image attributes with Jest?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I am writing unit tests and I want to test an `img` atrributes. However, when I make an assertion, I get mocked `img` attributes which is under `__mocks__`>`fileMock.js`. Because I mock files, I only get mocked file atrributes. How can I skip mocked files in my tests?

```
describe('Buttons', () => {

test('Clear filters work after filtering tools, workflows and using searchbar', async () => {
    render(<HeaderBar {...defaults} />);

    const clearFilterButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Clear Filters' });
    const toolsButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'TOOLS' });
    const selectedTools = await within(toolsButton).findByRole('img');
    expect(selectedTools).toHaveAttribute('src', 'images/tools-selected.png');

});
```

And test result is :

```
 Buttons › Clear filters work after filtering tools, workflows and using searchbar

expect(element).toHaveAttribute("src", "images/tools-selected.png") // element.getAttribute("src") === "images/tools-selected.png"

Expected the element to have attribute:
  src="images/tools-selected.png"
Received:
  src="test-file-stub"

  39 |         const toolsButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'TOOLS' });
  40 |         const selectedTools = await within(toolsButton).findByRole('img');
> 41 |         expect(selectedTools).toHaveAttribute('src', 'images/tools-selected.png');
```

I need to test real image, and skip mocking that `img` in my test.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a [manual user module mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules) defined in a `__mock__` folder next to your actual code.

In that case the mock is used in any test file where you call `jest.mock('moduleName')` unless [`automock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#automock-boolean) is set to `true` in which case the mock will *always* be used.

If you are explicitly mocking the file using `jest.mock('moduleName')` then simply remove that from the test file where you want to use the actual code instead of the mock.

If you have `automock` set to `true` in your Jest config then you can tell Jest to use the original code file in a given test by using [`jest.unmock('moduleName')`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestunmockmodulename).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I use manual user module mock and png extensions are being mocked under __mock__ > fileMock.js .  however test is still using mocked data. I used unmock before render in the test.

...
jest.unmock('./tools-selected.png');
render(<HeaderBar {...defaults} />);
...